# dynamic link URL contains location of wav file to be played by soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

On my page: http://s3.amazonaws.com/gccweb/h1/test1.html  we see soundmanger2 being used to create a simple play and download page.

My conferencing server that creates and hosts the recordings - also sends out an email with a reference to the file.  My email template on the server allows me to create a link that references the location URL of the audio file.

Q: How can I have the reference in the address bar?

1. Do I need a new js file?
2. Can I add some code to the soundmanager2.js ?
3. Can I add code to the player page only?

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.
You have 2 servers, and you want one server to receive an email with the reference to a file?

What is your goal, do you want to direct people to a webpage that plays the audio file?
I also don't really quite understand where the email comes in..

Comment: my description is really bad. I'll start again. [ at the bottom of my soundmanager2 web player page is the reference to the file that will be played. It's the usual < a href = etc. Her is my question. Is it possible to have the actual player page URL address bar contain the address of the player page FOLLOWED by the ? and then the location of the audio file on that other server?  So, yes, I do have the soundmanager2 software on my web hosting site and the actual audio files are on a secondary server. ... Is there a code that I can put into the < a href = that would 'grab' that location?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if I understand correctly you can use:

```
var params = window.location.href.split('?');
```

to fetch the address bar information via javascript.
You still need to split this up into some sort of key-value array and run some if statements if there actually is a valid parameter etc..

Once you have the name of the file, you can simply use:

```
soundManager.setup({
  url: 'swf/'
});

var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
   id: '1',
   url: urlToTheSoundFile,
   volume: 80,
   autoPlay: false,
});
```

to load the file into soundmanager. You can of course set autoPlay to true, or apply any other kind of visual graphics to it.

With soundmanager the soundfile does not have to be hosted on the server you are hosting the website on, you do however need to have access to the file. If you have a server with the file (www.iAmASoundServer.com/getSound.php?id=mySound.wav) you just need to parse this url into soundmanager. If you want people to be able to download this sound, again, all you have to do is put the url in an "a" tag (href="www.iAmASoundServer.com/getSound.php?id=mySound.wav").

As for your 3 questions:

**Do I need a new js file?**
You can use the standard soundmanager2.js file, this has hooks you can use on every imaginable event.

**Can I add some code to the soundmanager2.js ?**
Yes of course you can, though you probably wont need to. If you look at the [documentation](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) you will understand..

**Can I add code to the player page only?**
You can add code wherever you want, though it is advised to put all javascript related things at the bottom of your website.

Let me know if this answers your questions. I've got a feeling that this still doesn't quite answer your question.